# Missing Kernel.framework/Headers

Tags: macos, kernel, clang

I'm attempting to build an internal project that requires `libkern/OSAtomic.h` and `make` (using clang) is complaining that it is not found.

I'm using the latest version of XCode (6.2). My coworker has the following folder on his system:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Headers
```

I do not have this folder. What do I need to do to make sure my system headers are available?

Answer (score 0):

So sorry, I'm an idiot. I had not installed the CLT (command line tools) for XCode yet.